# Extracting Data from HTML File (VBA?)

Tags: html, css, vba, excel

I'm currently working on a project at work (I'm an intern), that is expected to take me a few weeks to complete. It's basically a migration copy and paste job from one website to another. In order to save myself time, boredom and possibly win myself a job (If I'm able to complete this in a timely manner), I'm looking at ways to automate the process. Currently I've figured each step in the process but one.

Basically, I have another automation program downloading the html file and converting it into a text file for each page on the site that needs to be copied over to the new one (over 1000). What I need to do with this html file is to extract just the body, I've identified an start and end point to extract from  to . Both these appear in all of the html files.

I'm currently attempting to use VBA in excel to open up the file, extract the data and write the result in a new file, from here I can automate the copy and paste process.

What I can't figure out is how to extract data between these two point. I can extract data between two strings i.e. "Start" & "End" however, I can't seem to extract data between two html tags. Any suggestions would be fantastic. I'm not a programmer, and I'm learning on the fly in order to complete this project ASAP.

Thanks again.

Comment: If you can do `start` and `end`, why can't you do `<body>` and `</body>` ? Welcome to Stack Overflow - people generally appreciate it you post the code you already tried to solve the problem with....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it would be done like this:

```
Sub Test() Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/analystestimates" ' should work for any URL
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        x = .document.body.innertext
        y = InStr(1, x, "Average Target Price:")
        Z = Mid(x, y, 6)

        Range("A1").Value = Trim(Z)

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

In your specific case, it should be something like this:

```
a = .document.body.innertext
b = InStr(1, x, "Start")
c = InStr(1, y, "End")

d = Mid(a, b, (c-b))

Range("A1").Value = Trim(d)
```

Comment: What do I need to set each one of the dimensions as? Or do I not?